# Regex For Numbers, Letters, Spaces and Hyphens Only

Tags: regex

I need a Regex For Numbers, Letters, Spaces and Hyphens Only.

Something like this 
        ^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$
 gets letters and numbers but I need one for the above. These are really hard to understand!

Comment: You can use: `^[a-zA-Z0-9\s-]+$`

Answer (score 5):

This is what you need:

```
/^[0-9A-Za-z\s\-]+$/
```